# What is the [church-local] tag for?

Tags: discussion

I'm looking at the [church-local](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/church-local) and I'm confused at its use.  I can see that it's made as a comparison to [church-universal](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/church-universal), but that doesn't answer the question of its use.

When I look at the questions, it doesn't help:

- [What are some of the benefits of going to church?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/2087/what-are-some-of-the-benefits-of-going-to-church)
- [Do I have to attend church every Sunday?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1054/do-i-have-to-attend-church-every-sunday)
- [Can I go to church on the internet?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1348/can-i-go-to-church-on-the-internet)

I can't seem to find a common thread between all these questions.  Could someone clarify for me exactly what this tag is meant to be used for?

Comment: I've updated the tags' excerpts to reflect @DJClayworth's definitions which were in the wiki.

Answer (score 3):

I think this is referring to the "local" church where you would commonly participate in worship and other activities with other believers.  I like to say "church as in the building" to differentiate this.  The "building" doesn't work so well when you consider that there are now "online" churches, although they are usually still based in a building/house and usually have a local head/board somewhere.

This is in contrast to the global body of all believers, which is also called the church.  I've called this the "body of Christ" as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you click on any tag it brings up questions with that tag; if you then go to the right of the screen and click "about >>>" that will bring up a description of the tag and its usage.

The short version is that this is for questions about groups of Christians that meet together.

For example "should churches always meet on a Sunday?" would be tagged with church-local; "what does it mean that the Church is the Bride of Christ" should be tagged with "church-universal". "Why do churches have steeples?" would be tagged with "church-building".

Comment: The tag wiki was added *after* (and partially because of) this question.  This question was asked because the questions related to the tag seemed to have no common theme.  Thanks, though.  This is good now that the wiki has been updated.